# How can I concatenate my code properly and make this more efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, csv

In my program I am trying to read in data from the file data.csv, the third set of data is a bunch of integers ranging from 1 to 200. After I read in this data I check to see  if that person gets better than 80%. If they get more than 80% they will have all of their data put into a new csv file. Unfortunately I get an error saying "can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple" and also I don't know how to but I believe that I should be able to make my code more efficient. Any help would be appreciated, ty!

```py
forename = []
surname = []
score = []
aForename = []
aSurname = []
aScore = []


f = open("data.csv", "r")
lineFromFile = f.readline()
while lineFromFile:
  currentLine = lineFromFile.split(',')
  forename.append(str(currentLine[0]))
  surename.append(str(currentLine[1]))
  score.append(int(currentLine[2]))
  lineFromFile = f.readline()
f.close()


for i in range(len(forename)):
  if 80 < (score[i]/200)*100:
    aForename.append(str(forename[i]))
    aSurename.append(str(surename[i]))
    aScore.append(int(score[i]))

f = open("revisedCSV.txt", "w") 
for i in range(len(aForename)):
  value = aForename[i],",",aSurename[i],",",aScore[i]
  f.write(value+'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: if you want to write better/faster code use context manager `with` and open file with that, also use for loop instead of while

Comment: Please always include the complete Traceback - formatted as code. Also any data that is causing problems - a small portion of your file. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code was creating a tuple. This should solve the problem.

```py
value = aForename[i] + "," + aSurename[i] + "," + str(aScore[i])
```

To explain it better:

```py
a = 'this is a ', 'tuple'
print(type(a))
print(a)

b = 'this is a ' + 'string'
print(type(b))
print(b)
```

Output:

```py
<class 'tuple'>
('this is a ', 'tuple')
<class 'str'>
this is a string
```

To make your code more efficient, as stated in the comments, open your files with `with` statement.